TS2339: Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'WritableSignal<Product[]>'
I am trying to add pagination to my Angular 10.1.0 project by slicing my data array. However, I get the TS2339: Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'WritableSignal<Data[]>' error.
Here is an extraction of my component:
export class Component implements OnInit {
  data = signal<Data[]>([]);
  currentPage: number = 1;

  constructor(private httoService: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.httpService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data.set(data);
    });
  }

  get paginatedData() {
    const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * 100;
    const end = start + 100;
    return this.data.slice(start, end);
  }

...
}

My http.service.ts:
export class HttpService {
  http = inject(HttpClient);
  private apiUrl = 'url'

  getProducts(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get<Data[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}

I have tried extracting the values before slicing:
const dataArray = Array.from(this.data().values)
but it returns 0.

The error message indicates that the slice method is not available on the data property, which is a WritableSignal<Data[]>. This is because WritableSignal is not an array, and therefore does not have a slice method. Try const dataArray = this.data.get(); // Get the value of the data signal

We need to execute the signal, get the array and then slice
  get paginatedData() {
    const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * 100;
    const end = start + 100;
    return this.data().slice(start, end);  // <- changed here!
  }


You can't use slice() on signal, but you can do it on signal's value by adding (). Simplest solution is this:
  get paginatedData() {
    const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * 100;
    const end = start + 100;
    return this.data().slice(start, end);
  }

But if you want to work with signals, you can replace getter with computed signal:
  paginatedData = computed(() => {
    const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * 100;
    const end = start + 100;
    return this.data().slice(start, end);
  }

This way your paginatedData will be signal, and you can use signal flow. You can simply use it in your html (or wherever you want) by using
paginatedData()

